# Replacement for reverse_related_entries in 2.x

Tags: relationships, navigation, reverse-related-entries, parent

This code comes from 1.6 days.

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="static" sort="asc" offset="1" dynamic="off"}
     {if static_parent_page=="0"}     
      <li>
       <a class="active"href="{url_title_path=static/three_tier_d}">{title}</a>
       {reverse_related_entries weblog="static"}
        {if count==1}<ul>{/if}
        <li><a  class="active" href="{url_title_path=static/three_tier_d}">{title}</a></li>
        {if count==total_results}</ul>{/if}
       {/reverse_related_entries}
      </li>
     {/if}
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Since relationships was overhauled in 2.x, the **reverse_related_entries tag** in the above doesn't work. I need help to re-code it for EE 2.6

Full page code is at:
http://www.train-ee.com/images/weblog/static_content_approach_d_activeclass.txt
The result of the code is this page:
http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/static/three_tier_d/

In a nutshell, the snippet does the following...
Each entry has a special field called **static_parent_page**. If it isn't set, then the field is 0 and thus a top level navigation link. If the field is set to another entry, then we assume it is a child entry. So the code will display every child entry of a parent entry.

A 1000 thanks for helping with this!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the name of the relationship field on your parent entries.

Instead of using `static_parent_page == 0`, try a namespaced `no_results`.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="static" sort="asc" offset="1" dynamic="off"}
  {static_parent_page}
    {if static_parent_page:no_results}
      <li>
       <a class="active" href="{url_title_path=static/three_tier_d}">{title}</a>
       {parents field="static_parent_page"}
        {if count == 1}<ul>{/if}
        <li><a class="active" href="{parents:url_title_path=static/three_tier_d}">{title}</a></li>
        {if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
       {/parents}
      </li>
    {/if}
  {/static_parent_page}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The [documentation about relationships](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) is really good.

Comment: static_parent_page is a field type relationship.
See:
http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/three-tier-static-content-in-expressionengine-approach-d
Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer helped you?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation for chat yet and I couldn't find a way to contact you. So, I gonna update my answer again. Please, test or look for me at twitter, so we can talk. @robsonsobral